# Why does R png() function not work on HPC but on my local system?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I wrote a script, that properly works in my local system to save the final output as a PNG but then when I threw it into HPC, It did not work and I am getting  the error I shared below.

Normally, PNG function works in my local system although my local has got less memory. So I do not think It is memory issue.

```
Error in png(file_name, width = 75000, height = 6500, type = "cairo",  :
  unable to start device 'png'
In addition: Warning message:
In png(file_name, width = 75000, height = 6500, type = "cairo",  :
  cairo error 'invalid value (typically too big) for the size of the input (surface, pattern, etc.)'
Execution halted
srun: error: fat-0002: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
```

Here is R script that I am currently using. Do you think what the problem is ? I could not find the solution in anywhere.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidypaleo)


setwd("~/path-to-dir")

refsbcf <- fread("file.tbl")

chr_list <- unique(refsbcf$V2)

plot_list = list()

for (i in 1:length(chr_list)) {
  current = which(refsbcf$V2 %in% chr_list[i])
  refsbcf_current = refsbcf[current,]
  p1 = ggplot(data = subset(refsbcf_current), aes(x=as.factor(V3), y=V5)) +
    geom_col_segs(position = "stack",size = 1)+    
    scale_x_discrete() +
    scale_fill_manual()+
    theme_bw() +
    facet_grid(vars(V1), scales = "free") +
    labs(x = "position", y = "coverage")+
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, hjust = 0.5,vjust = 0.5),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
          #hjust = 0, vjust = 0), 
          strip.background = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 3, angle = 90, hjust = 0),
          plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0.5, 0, 0), "inches"),
          panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "black"))
  plot_list[[i]] = p1
}

for (i in 1:length(chr_list)) {
  name = chr_list[i]
  file_name = paste("cov_TEST_",i, ".png", sep="")
  png(file_name, width = 75000, height = 6500, units = "px", pointsize = 10, res = 300)
  print(plot_list[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

And I am calling it using the batch script is here:

```
#SBATCH --job-name=R1
#SBATCH --partition=fat
#SBATCH --time=10:00:00
#SBATCH --qos=normal
#SBATCH --mail-type=END
#SBATCH --mem=300G

module load bio/R/4.0.0

srun Rscript script_visualization.R

module unload bio/R/4.0.0
```

Comment: Several graphics devices requires font information, that is the same (under Linux) as being able to say `x11()` to plot.  As an alternative you can use a Cairo plotting device to export a file -- see the Cairo package at https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html

Comment: two suggestions: 1. try ggplot's convenience wrapper `ggsave` to save each plot in the desired png format, 2. unless you need your plot objects later on, `ggsave` them right away instead of storing them in a list and using a separate loop only to save each list member anyway. HTH

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thank you for your answer. I checked Cairo package but I can't install it as I do not have admin permission on HPC. So I think I need to contact with system admin to use it as far as I understood.

@I_O 's suggesstion would work for me, and I tried it but now the problem is that I can't draw a big png file even though I set the parameter. 

``` Error in limitsize && any(dim >= 50) : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
Calls: ggsave -> plot_dim 
```
Also,I can't set the unit parameter as "px". . I can use "in" for units and not more than 50*50 but I need bigger ones.

Comment: Mind that normally a vector rather than a raster version of your plot will need considerably less memory/disk space (vector as in vector graphics, not R's data structure). Unless you're really dealing with raster data, an svg or pdf output will consume less ressources (and scale without quality loss) than its png or tif "equivalent" (see e.g.: https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/raster-vs-vector-file-formats). You could try `ggsave('plot.svg', ...)`